# Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadPets
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{

ArrayList <Pet> petList = new ArrayList <Pet>;
Scanner inFile = null;
String name;
Pet p;
try
{
  inFile = new Scanner
    (new FileInputStream ("pets.txt"));
}

catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
  System.out.println("problem opening file.");
  System.exit(0);
}
while (inFile.hasNextLine())
{
  name = inFile.NextLine();
  p = newPet(name);
  petList.add(p);
}
inFile.close();
}
} 

    1 error found:
```

File: C:\Users\remixt\Desktop\java\ReadPets.java  [line: 9]
Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

I keep getting that error, no idea how to fix it.
Also i get the error The constructor Pet(java.lang.String) is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList <Pet> petList = new ArrayList <Pet>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parentheses in your constructor call (`new ArrayList<Pet>`)